# QuickSort Algorithm not passing a test harness

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, quicksort

I have made a QuickSort algorithm with a group for practicing our java coding outside of class (not a homework question). My code seems to fit in with what most have for a QuickSort implementation, but when running a test harness, it fails 5/7 tests. Is anything blatantly wrong with my implementation?

```
public class QuickSort implements SortInterface {

    public void swap(Note[] Note, int i, int j) {
        Note temp = Note[i];
        Note[i] = Note[j];
        Note[j] = temp;
    }


    // TODO Auto-generated method stub pseudo here
    public void quicksort(Note[] Note, long m, long l){

        if(m<l){
            //choose a pivot, median of three
            long pivot_index = pivotMaker(Note, m, l);
            //partition the array about the pivot, return index of pivot, where swaps happen
            pivot_index = partition(Note, pivot_index);

            quicksort(Note, m, pivot_index-1 ); // breaks up lesser than pivot side
            quicksort(Note, pivot_index+1, l); // breaks up higher than pivot side
        } // end if
    }

    public long pivotMaker(Note [] Note, long m, long l) // physically creates a median of three pivot
    {

            int center = (int)((m + l) / 2);
            // order left & center
            if (Note[(int)(m)].getID() > Note[center].getID())
              swap(Note,(int)m, center);
            // order left & right
            if (Note[(int)(m)].getID() > Note[(int)l].getID())
              swap(Note,(int)m, (int)l);
            // order center & right
            if (Note[center].getID() > Note[(int)l].getID())
              swap(Note,center, (int)l);

            swap(Note,center, (int)l - 1); // put pivot on right
            return Note[(int)(l-1)].getID(); // return median value
          }
        //median of 3

        // end pivot maker

    public int partition(Note[] Note, long pivot_index){ // will place the pivot in its final index         
        return(0);
    }

    public Note[] sort(Note[] s) {
         quicksort(s, 0, s.length-1);
         return s;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // make an array of notes
        Note q = new Note(" ", " ");
        Note n = new Note("CSCI 230 Project Plan", 
                "Each person will number their top 5 choices.\n" +
                "By next week, Dr. Hill will assign which piece\n" +
                "everyone will work on.\n");
        n.tag("CSCI 230");
        n.tag("final project");

        Note[] Note = {q,n, new Note(" ", " "), new Note(" ", " "), new Note(" ", " "), new Note(" ", " "), new Note(" ", " ")};
        //print out not id's
        //call QuickSort
        System.out.println(Note);
        //print out note_id's
    }

}
```

Comment: you could add some minimal test case that fails

Comment: Where's the partition code? It would probably be better to leave the pivot in the center rather than swapping it to the right. Depending on the partition method, the left half recursive call is either quicksort(data, low, pivot-1), or quicksort(data, low, pivot), while the right half is usually quicksort(data, pivot+1, high) .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be easier if you included a successful and a failed test. But it's pretty clear that partition isn't implemented yet:

```
`public int partition(Note[] Note, long pivot_index)` always returns `0`.
```

Also, you're using the index `l-1` where I think you meant to use `l`:

```
swap(Note,center, (int)l - 1);
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, I can't believe I overlooked that.